# Access classes/objects of Play Framework App through Scala Interpreter

Tags: eclipse, scala, playframework, interpreter, playframework-2.1

How can I access the classes and objects of a Play Framework App from within the Scala Interpreter in Eclipse? For instance, I have the object `controllers.Scraper`, but if I try to use it in the interpreter window, I get the error

```
object Scraper is not a member of package controllers
```

How can I make it work?